# Can Durable Activity Functions use binding attributes?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

It appears that I cannot have an activity function which uses a Blob binding. The following gives runtime errors:

```
[StorageAccount("AzureWebJobsStorage")]
[FunctionName("LoadBlobFromBlobStorage")]
public static async Task<string> Run([ActivityTrigger] string blobName,
[Blob("containerName/directoryName/{blobName}", FileAccess.ReadWrite, Connection = AzureWebJobsStorage")] CloudBlockBlob blob,
ILogger log)
{
    ...
}
```

I get multiple failed binding error messages. Do Durable Functions not resolve bindings?

EDIT: add error messages (with reduced verbosity ...):

```
Azure Functions Core Tools (2.4.379 Commit hash: ab2c4db3b43f9662b82494800dd770698788bf2d)
Function Runtime Version: 2.0.12285.0
2019-02-21T18:25:32.165 [Error] Error indexing method 'LoadBlobFromBlobStorage'
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Indexers.FunctionIndexingException : Error indexing method 'LoadBlobFromBlobStorage' ---> System.InvalidOperationException : Can't bind Blob to type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob'.
Possible causes:
1) Tried binding to 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobDirectory...' but user type assembly was 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobDirectory... .
2) Tried binding to 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer...' but user type assembly was 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobDirectory... .
3) Tried binding to 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Blobs.Bindings.BlobsExtensionConfigProvider+MultiBlobContext, Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' but user type assembly was 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobDirectory... .
4) Tried binding to 'System.IO.Stream, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' but user type assembly was 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobDirectory... .
5) Tried binding to 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob...' but user type assembly was 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobDirectory... .
6) Tried binding to 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudPageBlob...' but user type assembly was 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobDirectory... .
7) Tried binding to 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudAppendBlob...' but user type assembly was 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobDirectory... .
8) Tried binding to 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.ICloudBlob...' but user type assembly was 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobDirectory... .

   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Bindings.GenericCompositeBindingProvider`1.TryCreateAsync[TAttribute](BindingProviderContext context) at C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Bindings\BindingProviders\GenericCompositeBindingProvider.cs : 89
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
```

Comment: Durable Functions' activities do resolve bindings; the functionality was added in [this PR](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/pull/172). What binding error messages are you seeing?

Comment: @KatyShimizu, I added the error messages.

Comment: @KatyShimizu, hmm, oddly I coded up Chris' example 1 from the PR you refer to and I get no indexing errors.

Comment: So to reduce verbosity I removed some of the 5) message. In full it says: `5) Tried binding to 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=9.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' but user type assembly was 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=9.3.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.` basically trying to bind to the same type but different point release. Not sure how to resolve which version of the enclosing library I need.

Comment: Maybe [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54823793/azure-durable-function-microsoft-azure-webjobs-host-error-indexing-method).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the package required are installed e.g.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="3.0.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.24" />
```

And in the blob input binding, for binding type `CloudBlobDirectory`, the path should be in the format of `containerName/directoryName`. See `container` in your sample which is suspicious.

We could also put the incoming parameter blobName in blob path to get CloudBlockBlob directly.

```
[Blob("containerName/directoryName/{blobName}", FileAccess.ReadWrite, Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] CloudBlockBlob blob
```

**Update**

Make sure we don't install `WindowsAzure.Storage` >= v9.3.2, there seems a bug when binding to Storage related data type like `CloudBlockBlob`. See the [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3784#issuecomment-434118970) tracked.

When we create a v2 Function Project, `Microsoft.NET.SDK.Functions` references `WindowsAzure.Storage` 9.3.1 by default. This version works well, no need to install the package separately.

Or we could use datatype like `Stream` or `string` with new version Storage SDK.

Comment: I updated my `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage` to version `3.0.3` from `3.0.0` and changed my `BlobAttribute` signature to match yours but I still get the error messages. Removing the topmost `StorageAccountAttribute` also doesn't help.